# EventLog stops sending EntryWritten events after clear

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008-r2, event-log

In Windows 2008 server, when I clear the EventLog, I stop getting subsequent EntryWritten events. The code to see this is very simple:

```
private void eventLog1_EntryWritten(object sender, System.Diagnostics.EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
{
  label1.Text = "Got entry at " + DateTime.Now;
}

private void write_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  eventLog1.WriteEntry("Hello");
}

private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  eventLog1.Clear();
}


  this.eventLog1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
  this.eventLog1.Log = "MY_LOG";
  this.eventLog1.Source = "Test";
  this.eventLog1.SynchronizingObject = this;
  this.eventLog1.EntryWritten += new System.Diagnostics.EntryWrittenEventHandler(this.eventLog1_EntryWritten);
```

In Windows 2003 server, the code works as expected.
Does anyone have an idea why this happens, or how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft confirmed this is a bug in Windows 7 and 2008 Server.

The workaround is to create a new EventLog object, and add an entry to the log before setting EnableRaisingEvents to true.

Hopefully this will be fixed...